# Maven aggregate project with Scala module

Tags: scala, maven

I have a parent Maven project and a child module with both Scala and Java code. The child project compiles just fine by itself when running `mvn scala:compile` in its directory, but the compilation of the parent project with `mvn compile` doesn't see Scala source files.

Parent pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>mvn-sandbox</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>mvn-sandbox</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <modules>
    <module>mvn-scala</module>
  </modules>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>4.4.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <scalaVersion>2.11.12</scalaVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Scala module pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>mvn-scala</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>mvn-scala</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <parent>
      <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvn-sandbox</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>add-source</id>
              <phase>generate-sources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <sources>
                  <source>src/main/scala</source>
                </sources>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>add-test-source</id>
              <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>add-test-source</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <sources>
                  <source>src/test/scala</source>
                </sources>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>4.4.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <scalaVersion>2.11.12</scalaVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
<!--        <plugin>-->
<!--          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--          <version>3.8.0</version>-->
<!--        </plugin>-->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: I don't have any errors, it just skips Scala files